# How does Tomcat load the different war files?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, war

How does Tomcat (or any Web application server) manage to load the different WAR files separately, though it works in one JVM process? They may have the same classes and other resources, but it has to guarantee consistency and isolation of applications.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with one Thread, but typically WAR files are loaded into their own class loaders. This way you can have multiple versions of classes with the same name. All you need to make sure is to instantiate the servlets from the corresponding class loader. Threads might need to get the class loader set as context class loader (depending on the code you cann), but thats not strictly needed. OSGi for example has a similar concept with bundles and no TCCL set by default.

Comment: @eckes, thanks for your explanation. So, does Tomcat create a new classloader for each war file to load classes? How do you think, is it worth have a look inside tomcat's code to understand, or can I read about it somewhere?

Comment: Yes it does, see the ClassLoader HowTo: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Great! It's definitely what I need.

Comment: great, I turned it into an answer (with some more backgroud).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tomcat creates (Web) application class loaders for each deployed WAR. It has some common class loaders. The overall hierachy is best described in the class loader howto:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

BTW: Tomcat does an incredible amount of resource management in order to allow applications to be undeployed. This is described here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

and ties tightly into class loaders and class unloading.